# tensorflow 2 install on mac by conda

Tags: macos, tensorflow, anaconda

Hi i'm trying to install tensorflow but getting package conflicts due to existing packages as numpy for example

**Thanks for your help**

**This is part of the error massage:**

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions

```
Package numpy conflicts for:
tensorflow-base -> keras-applications[version='>=1.0.8'] -> numpy[version='>=1.13.3|>=1.9.1']
tensorflow-estimator -> numpy[version='>=1.13.3']
tensorflow-estimator -> tensorflow-base[version='>=2.0.0,<2.1.0a0'] -> numpy[version='>=1.14.6,<2.0a0|>=1.16.5,<2.0a0']
tensorflow-hub -> numpy[version='>=1.12.0']
tensorflow-datasets -> numpy
tensorflow -> tensorboard[version='>=2.0.0'] -> numpy[version='>=1.12|>=1.12.0|>=1.16|>=1.16.5,<2.0a0|>=1.14.6,<2.0a0|>=1.13.3,<2.0a0']
tensorflow-probability -> numpy[version='>=1.13.3']
tensorflow-probability -> tensorflow-base[version='>=1.15.0'] -> numpy[version='>=1.14.6,<2.0a0|>=1.16.5,<2.0a0']
keras -> numpy[version='>=1.9.1']
keras -> h5py -> numpy[version='>=1.11.3,<2.0a0|>=1.16.6,<2.0a0|>=1.14.6,<2.0a0|>=1.15.1,<2.0a0|>=1.9.3,<2.0a0']
keras-gpu -> keras-base=2.3.1 -> numpy[version='>=1.9.1']
tensorflow-base -> numpy[version='>=1.13.3,<2.0a0|>=1.14.6,<2.0a0|>=1.16.5,<2.0a0']

Package tensorflow conflicts for:
tensorflow-probability -> tensorflow[version='>=1.14.0']
tensorflow
tensorflow-eigen -> tensorflow[version='1.10.0|1.11.0|1.12.0|1.13.1|1.15.0|2.0.0|1.9.0']
keras -> tensorflow[version='<2.0']
tensorflow-datasets -> tensorflow[version='>=1.14']
tensorflow-mkl -> tensorflow[version='1.11.0|1.12.0|1.13.1|1.15.0|2.0.0|1.9.0']
tensorflow-hub -> tensorflow[version='>=1.14.0|>=1.7.0']
tensorflow-datasets -> tensorflow-metadata -> tensorflow
tensorflow-metadata -> tensorflow
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conda is designed to prevent these kinds of conflicts by creating separate, self-contained Python environments for different projects. Run these commands in your Terminal app:

```
conda create -n tf-env # create new environment named tf-env
conda activate tf-env
pip install --upgrade pip # upgrade to latest version of pip
pip install tensorflow
```

That will install all of the packages you need, with the versions required by TensorFlow.

When you're done working in TensorFlow and want to go back to your normal Python environment, run `conda deactivate`. To return to the TensorFlow environment, run `conda activate tf-env` again.